# DropoutWrapper in tensorflow and test time scaling

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I learnt in the [CS231n class](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#reg) that during the test time we need to scale the activations by the same factor we used as a dropout probability of training. When using the DropoutWrapper in tensorflow I don't see any parameter that will allow me to do this test time scaling.

Why is it missing? Is it necessary for RNNs? What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need scaling on inference, because `tf.nn.dropout` apply scale at the train time (from [tf.nn.dropout documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dropout) ):

> With probability `keep_prob`, outputs the input element scaled up by `1 / keep_prob`, otherwise outputs `0`. The scaling is so that the expected sum is unchanged.

Comment: My question was about RNN's DropoutWrapper (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/dff64beac8570d910f83774087642bb6a3fda96a/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py), and I don't see scaling mentioned neither in its documentation, nor in it's source

Comment: it has same behavior, you can check it in the code.

Comment: I just noticed that it does not work properly - when I set the probabilities to 1.0 my output is about half the scale it should be. During training i used probability of 0.5. Any ideas?